# .net Windows app in a web page

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wpf

I am developing a feature related to Microsoft Outlook which has support only for Windows library.

However, I have to put this into a web page for the users. In the process of consuming the windows application into a web page, I have written a Windows application using C# and integrated it with a WPF solution and trying to package this as an ActiveX.

This would require the users to download the ActiveX on their local machines which I would like to avoid. Is there a better way to achieve this (Windows app to web)?

Comment: http://fayde.io/ -- Doesn't require a plugin or ActiveX.

Comment: I don't get the relationship between MS Outlook and the web page you are talking about, however, using ActiveX is something you should avoid at all costs.

Comment: If you provide some details of what your app does, exactly, we can suggest a tweaked version of your approach. I think this kind of integration is nothing but a headache.

Comment: I am trying to drag outlook attachments and drop it on a text area in a web page so that user can upload it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You are a little far from you objectives.

I assume you are referring to [Exchange Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13082) and not MS Outlook.

For Outlook you can [develop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905340.aspx) add-in for your desktop (through a local .dll) but, on the server side is another story. It is very unlikely (and not recommended) to run [MS Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) on a server.

You can use the same set of [API](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42951) in use by ['OWA' (Outlook Web Access)](https://www.microsoft.com/exchange/2007/code/OWA/index.html) they are very well documented, however, not for newbies.

[Active-X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX) and most of the user-side executables are today, to say the less, obsolete, 'deprecated'. Also, with multitude of different access devices using your application, will be almost impossible to make them compatible. HTML is today the most common minimum denominator.

Comment: You are right. I am using exchange web services(EWS) and for what I am doing (drag and drop outlook attachments), it is supported only on windows applications as the interfaces in EWS are windows interfaces. I considered outlook add in but did not go with it since its version based and maintenance becomes a headache when an older version reaches end of life.